# Java enum class, what is in the first line??? is it constructor?

Tags: java, enums

```
enum Size
{
    SMALL("S"), MEDIUM("M"), LARGE("L"), EXTRA_LARGE("XL");
    private Size(String abbreviation) {
        this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
    }
    public String getAbbreviation() { return abbreviation;}
    private String abbreviation;
}
```

I know that all enum in java is subclass of Enum.
What's this line:

```
SMALL("S"), MEDIUM("M"), LARGE("L"), EXTRA_LARGE("XL");
```

Is this constructor?
Seems weird syntax.

Need explanation.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SMALL("S"), MEDIUM("M"), LARGE("L"), EXTRA_LARGE("XL");
```

is list of static final fields holding instances of this enum. You can think of it as equivalent of this code

```
public static final Size SMALL = new Size("S");
public static final Size MEDIUM = new Size("M");
public static final Size LARGE = new Size("L");
public static final Size EXTRA_LARGE = new Size("XL");
```

Answer (score 0):

The definition of enum literals calling a constructor with the respective values.